# How to convert Html code to template output in browser

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to convert `HTML` in template.
As seen in image **content** should show as a template. 
I am using `table` to show . but now i need to show it in template output

Here is my Code:

```
<table id="datatable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <span id='errfrmMsg'></span>
    <thead>
        <tr>        
            <th scope="col" id="">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" id="">Content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
            $templ_id = $_REQUEST['templ_id'];
            $getTemplateQuery = mysql_query("select * from templates where id = $templ_id");
            $getTemplateRow = mysql_fetch_array($getTemplateQuery);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="125"><?php echo $getTemplateRow['templ_name'];?></td>
            <td valign="top" width="319">
            <?php
                echo $templContent = $getTemplateRow['templ_content'];
?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an Output:

[image]

Comment: where u have placed the html content in a div or textarea.

Comment: inside the td or textarea?

Comment: Where is that data storred? Can you access it in JS? is it a PHP problem or JS?

Comment: Inside the table->tr->td "content" td->tr>->table

Comment: Can you add some code of how the PHP is build up to make this.

Comment: can u post sample code which ur using?

Comment: You mean you want the HTML to be shown as a real table, as opposed to as source code? You are being very cryptic.

Comment: any server side code used in this or pure HTML & JS

Comment: @sverri: yes i wants to show html to be shown in real ad shown a website template

Comment: echo $htmlContent = htmlspecialchars_decode($content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question, try outputting with:

`$html = htmlspecialchars_decode($content)`

EDIT:

`echo $templContent = htmlspecialchars_decode($getTemplateRow['templ_content']);`

Comment: People were downvoting you because you didn't (initially) provide us with any code and your question was badly worded, so our answers were just guesses. Providing code is the simplest way to make what you are trying to ask more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this this will help You

```
<?php

echo $htmlContent = htmlspecialchars_decode($getTemplateRow['templ_content']) 

?>
```